# reactjs - how to switch on and off updates in a child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a ReactJS that uses a child component that updates when it does not need to.

I want to control when that child updates by providing it with my own shouldComponentUpdate function.  Can this be done and how?

Please note the comments below refer to the first version of this question which did not at all reflect the original problem and the solution that the discussion led to.

Comment: Is what you are trying to modify an exposed method?

Comment: Essentially, I have a parent component, and I wish to give the child component a "shouldComponentUpdate" function to run, which the child component does not currently have.

Comment: Try setting your child component's `ref` property and then add the method to the ref in your `componentDidMount`. `ref={ component => this.childComponent = component }` and in `componentDidMount` this.childComponent.shouldComponentUpdate = () => { ... }`

Comment: @KyleRichardson ha !  Well whilst you were writing that comment, I wondered if such a solution might work and asked a separate SO question precisely asking if what you suggest is possible.  I'll give it try.  thanks.

Comment: If it is a functionality why don't you submit a pull request?

Comment: @siva well if I can make this work then I can go back to the repo and tell him I have found a solution and show the shouldComponentUpdate function.

Comment: @DukeDougal Let me know how you do :)

Comment: @DukeDougal That's a good idea. try it out

Comment: I Put Kyle's idea into an answer - Kyle if you want the points/credit then copy it and I'll make it the winner.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: this is not the right way to solve the original problem that I had.  Whilst Kyle's answer is correct, the right way to solve it is to wrap the component that is rerendering too much in a higher order component that implements its own shouldComponentUpdate function.

@Kyle Richardson gets the credit for this answer.  It works beautifully!

To illustrate Kyle's solution, two buttons that switch off updates in a child component and switch them back on again.

The assumption here is that you have refs to the child component (in this case this.refs.table)

```
  <button
    onClick={() => {if (!!this.refs.table) {this.refs.table.shouldComponentUpdate = () => true}}}>
    child component updates on
  </button>
)

  <button
    onClick={() => {if (!!this.refs.table) {this.refs.table.shouldComponentUpdate = () => false}}}>
    child component updates off
  </button>
```

Be aware that this will clobber any existing shouldComponentUpdate function.  You could probably somehow extend/override/compose the existing function but in my case I do not care because there is no existing shouldComponentUpdate.